# Template Contexts not recognized from external file (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates

So, I've been editing a website and have many JavaScript functions that utilize the Contexts that the views.py file passes to the page. Until now, these functions have been contained in the base.html file and so have been loaded onto every page directly. However, to make things cleaner, I copy and pasted all the functions to an external .js file. Now, rather than use the contexts, the functions consider them to be literal strings.

Example:

```
    $('#title').text('{{ event.name }}');
```

The above line will actually set the text of the element to say "{{ event.name }}" rather than the name of the event. Any ideas on how to fix this? I really don't want to keep these functions in the base file where they can be seen by anyone who inspects the page source.

Comment: If the code is in a .js file they can still be seen by those who inspect those files.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you put your javascript functions in an external file or in your base.html it would still get exposed to the user. Only a minification of the file would actually help to trick the user from seeing the actual values but with javascript all your code is public.

Why you're having this problem is because when you rendered the javascript inline (in your base.html) you had access to the template context.
This is no longer the case and the Django template engine doesn't interpolate your `{{ event.name }}` anymore.

The problem you're facing as well is a good one. You should never mix and match javascript with Djangos template language or any template language for that matter and the only way of fixing it is to

```
a) start pulling the values from the DOM ie. render a proper DOM 
b) to start to fetch the values from the server, traditionally using AJAX.
```

And the smallest example that I can muster at the moment is below:

Your view:

```
def my_django_view(request):
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'meaningoflife':42}), mimetype='application/json')
```

Your HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="myMeaning" value="{{ meaningoflife }}" />
```

Your javascript

```
var meaning = document.querySelector('#myMeaning').value;
alert(meaning); //should alert 42.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you return some form of **render_to_response** which takes a template argument and a context argument. What the **render_to_response** function does is read your template, and replace all *{{ placeholders }}* with the values passed via the context dictionary.

Templates are essentially a complex version of this

```
"""
<h1>{{ person.name }}</h1> 
<p>{{ person.phone_number }}</p>
""".format(person)
```

The problem is the templating engine does not know files specified by a scripts src attribute is actually a Django template. To fix this don't use the script src attribute. Instead do something like this.

```
<!--base.html-->
<h1>Site Title</h1>
<p>Some content</p>
<script>
{% include 'jsfile.js' %}
</script>
```

Using the include statement should do the trick.